# Selenium webdriver error when trying to lunch tests on a remote machine

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to run my web app tests using selenium on iE on a remorte machine. My tests run successfully locally but when I try to run them on a remorte XP OS using IE8, I get this log error : org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Help please ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible causes are

- Selenium Server Standalone is NOT started on the remote machine
- Selenium Server Standalone is started BUT inside code wrong IP address is written

Follow the steps written below in order to get things work:

1) Download Selenium Server Standalone JAR file : http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar in the remote machine (IP address of remote machine let say: **192.168.10.100**)

2) From remote machine, run the following command to start Server Standalone:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar
```

3) Ensure IEDriverServer path is also set in that machine. Information is avialble here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

4) After all the above setting done write following sample code to open IE in remote machine:

```
public class IERemoteWebDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Assuming Remote machine IP address '192.168.10.100'
        String remote_address = "http://192.168.10.100:4444/wd/hub";
        URL remote_url = new URL(remote_address);

        DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        WebDriver wbdv = new RemoteWebDriver(remote_url, dc);
        wbdv.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/");

    }

}
```

This should work!

Comment: Thanks mfsi_sitamj
You right, the problem was that I forgot to start the server standalone : java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=IEDriverServer.exe Now it works :)
Now it works ! 
But I have another problem, hope you can help...
In my test, I should download txt files automatically with selenium using IE. But the problem is : when the file is downloaded, a pop up window appears asking me to save the file manually. and this blocks the progression of tests until I click manually on the save button.
Do you know a way  to get this pop up not open on IE8 ?

Comment: Please close this question by accepting the correct answer and create a separate question for the issue you mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

One possibly issue could be that your IE8 browser does not have Protected Enabled. 
Open a new browser and then go to Tools->Internet Options->Security,
make sure all the zones have Enable Protected Mode selected.

Comment: Thanks thomas... but my internet security options are all enabled on the same level. I've already got this problem but I've solved it. 
The problem was that I forgot to start the server standalone : java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=IEDriverServer.exe 
Now it works :)